# my audio player in NextJS with hls js doesn't play the audio in vercel but on local work

Tags: next.js, vercel, hls.js

First this is my code when i load the audio

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(Hls.isSupported()){
        if (hlsRef?.current) {
            hlsRef.current.destroy()
        }
        if (audioPlayer?.current) {                
            hlsRef.current = new Hls();
            hlsRef.current.attachMedia(audioPlayer.current);
            hlsRef.current.on(Hls.Events.MEDIA_ATTACHED, () => {
                hlsRef.current?.loadSource(props.props.data.data?.streamingUrl);
                hlsRef.current?.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, () => {
                    hlsRef.current?.on(Hls.Events.LEVEL_LOADED, (_: string, data: any) => {
                        const duration: number = data.details.totalduration;
                        setDuration(duration);
                        setCurrentTime(0);
                    })
                }); 
            })
        }            
    } else {
        audioPlayer.current.src = props.props.data.data?.streamingUrl;
        setDuration(duration);
        setCurrentTime(0);
    }
}, [])
```

I think I found the error, but i don't know how to solve it

this is the network in the browse

[network in local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiNRs.png)

this is the browse in server (vercel)

[network browse in vercel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91giP.png)

it seems that the audio is not completely downloaded or something like that

Does anyone know how I can solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with the hls.js configuration

```
const config = { enableWorker: false }             
hlsRef.current = new Hls(config);
```

the worker seems to be to improve the performance and avoid lag/frame drops, can be a conflict with hls.js